# Unable to run jhipster, complaining about "nodeSetup' task

Tags: jhipster

Wen I am trying to start jhipster project (on ubuntu, gradle 1.8), I have the following error message:

```
gradle bootRun

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':nodeSetup'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.726 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the reason.
There is a version compatibility between Gradle 1.8 and 2.0.

I started again using the one come with the project:
./gradlew bootRun
and it works.